# send pygal line chart in mail using mandrill api

Tags: python, html, email, mandrill, pygal

from past week I am trying to create a simple line chart using pygal python library & send the resulting mail using mandrill api.

I placed my render result in "figure" tag as specified in pygal documentation.

I am able to send the email but it is completely blank.

following is my code.

```
    line_chart = pygal.Line()
    line_chart.title = 'Browser usage evolution (in %)'
    line_chart.x_labels = map(str, range(2002, 2013))
    line_chart.add('Firefox', [None, None, 0, 16.6,   25,   31, 36.4, 45.5, 46.3, 42.8, 37.1])
    line_chart.add('Chrome',  [None, None, None, None, None, None,    0,  3.9, 10.8, 23.8, 35.3])
    line_chart.add('IE',      [85.8, 84.6, 84.7, 74.5,   66, 58.6, 54.7, 44.8, 36.2, 26.6, 20.1])
    line_chart.add('Others',  [14.2, 15.4, 15.3,  8.9,    9, 10.4,  8.9,  5.8,  6.7,  6.8,  7.5])
    chart = line_chart.render()

    html = """<html>
            <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kozea.github.com/pygal.js/javascripts/svg.jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kozea.github.com/pygal.js/javascripts/pygal-tooltips.js"></script>
            </head>
           <body>
            <figure>"""
    html += chart
    html += "</figure></body></html>"

    try:
        mandrill_client = mandrill.Mandrill(MANDRILL_API_KEY)
        message = {}
        message['from_email'] = constants.REPORTS
        message['subject'] = 'Sending report of non reporting gps devices.'

        for email_id in send_to:
            to_dict = {}
            to_dict['email'] = str(email_id)
            to.append(to_dict)

        message['to'] = to
        message['preserve_recipients'] = True                                   
        message['html'] = str(html)

        result = mandrill_client.messages.send(message=message, async=False, ip_pool=constants.MANDRILL_MAIN_POOL, send_at=constants.SEND_AT) 
    except mandrill.Error, e:
        print 'A mandrill error occurred: %s - %s' % (e.__class__, e)
```

can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? I am in a similar situation.

Comment: no...not until now... :(

Answer (score 0):

Email clients cannot render Javascript. The chart that you are attaching needs to be rendered by pygal.js, which fails since email cannot render Javascript.